# CPU Clock speed vs number of cores for Cycles rendering with iMac?

Tags: rendering

I tried finding a previous post of mine but was unable to so I am asking for more info.

Apologies for the noob question but I am trying to decide between two iMacs since my current Late 2014 iMac is chugging more and more when rendering files using the Cycles engine:

**2019 27" iMac:**

- 3.6GHz 8-core 9th-generation Intel Core i9 processor, Turbo Boost up to 5.0GHz
- 8GB 2666MHz DDR4 memory (Upgrade the RAM to 64GB via 3rd party)
- Radeon Pro Vega 48 with 8GB of HBM2 memory
- 1TB SSD storage

**OR**

Current **27" iMac Pro**:

- 3.2GHz 8-core Intel Xeon W processor, Turbo Boost up to 4.2GHz
- 64GB 2666MHz DDR4 ECC memory
- Radeon Pro Vega 56 with 8GB of HBM2 memory
- 1TB SSD storage

I googled a lot but still do not quite understand is it is better to have a higher clock speed (GHz) or number of Core to render files faster.

There is about a $2k difference between the two iMacs but want to know if that difference is worth it in the long run.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You can't find the answer cause it is consider opinion base that should not exist in BSE. And the question itself almost has nothing to do with Blender. Yet, core number is important for parallel process like final render chunks. The processor speed is important for calculate things that is not able to process in parallel. Both are important and you should google the specified performance between these CPUs.

Comment: @Hikariztw: Thank you for your feedback. I included computer specifications is to understand which set of specifications would benefit me more efficiently while using Blender with its Cycles engine. That's why I found it relevant to ask before going through with a purchase as I will be using Blender with it a lot. Thank you also for explaining what the number of cores does vs the processor speed. I will have to Google what a parallel process is since I am not very computer savvy in that aspect. I am not even sure if adding more RAM into the mix would make that much of a difference.